# L2TP / IPSec VPN Issue

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I am trying to configure L2TP client on our Ubuntu 22.04 Server. I have configured the credentials and see the following errors in the Log

```
May  2 09:31:39 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 101 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:39 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 101 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:40 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 12 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:40 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 12 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:40 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 101 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:40 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 101 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:42 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 12 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:42 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 12 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:42 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 101 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:42 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 101 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:46 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 101 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:46 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 101 Dumping.
May  2 09:31:46 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: Can not find tunnel 12 (refhim=0)
May  2 09:31:46 nl-live NetworkManager[31815]: xl2tpd[31815]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 39479, tunnel = 12 Dumping.
```

Any ideas what i am missing?

I also see that any change i make to the interface of Network Manager, does not persist and gets reverted to earlier value when i enable the VPN.

So for example, if earlier the name of VPN connection was `VPN OLD` if change the name of the VPN to "VPN NEW" and try to enable the VPN,the name get reverted back to `VPN OLD`.

Any help on how to fix this would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to xl2tpd 1.3.16-1ubuntu0.1 or later, e.g.:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade xl2tpd
```

I would also recommend installing the newer network-manager-l2tp (and network-manager-l2tp-gnome) package(s) from :

- [https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp](https://launchpad.net/%7Enm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp)

I have no idea what is going wrong with the rename, but it wouldn't hurt doing a `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade all of the packages, it might even fix that rename issue.